# Multiple drop down lists with same name pre-selecting different values

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an MVC application that accepts a list of Manager IDs for a given department.  Each department can have zero or more managers.  To achieve this, there is an initial drop down list with all available managers.  If the user wishes to add another manager, the "Add Manager button is clicked, an ajax request is made to a partial view that returns a new list of managers (with the name control name, but a different ID value).  When the user submits the form, the array of manager IDs can be accessed easily, but when editing, any attempt to pre-select the entry in the drop down results in ALL drop downs having the same selected entry. I believe this is due to the drop downs all having the same name.

I've tried pre-selecting the listitem in both the generation of the drop down list, and in the controller, neither works.

ViewModel:

```
public class AddDepartmentVM
{
    // Form data
    public List<int> ManagerIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Initial View:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("AddDepartment", "Departments", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addDepartment", className = "form", role = "form" }))
 {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

  // Hide the ID field
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID);

  <div class="form-row container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
     <label for="Description">Department Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "test-class", aria_describedby = "descriptionHelp", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description) })
     <small id="descriptionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Department names should be approved by Corporate &amp IT.</small>
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
     <label for="RecordStatusID">Status</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecordStatusID, new SelectList(recordStatuses.SearchResults, "ID", "Description"), new { @class = "some-class" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecordStatusID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-row container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
     <label for="Manager">Manager</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
     @for (int index = 0; index < managerCount; index++)
     {
      // Declarations
      int selectedID = (Model.ManagerIDs != null && Model.ManagerIDs[index] != 0) ? Model.ManagerIDs[index] : 0;

      // If this was an actual manager
      if (Model.ManagerIDs != null && Model.ManagerIDs[index] != 0)
      {
       // Save the selctedID
       selectedID = Model.ManagerIDs[index];
      }

      <div>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManagerIDs, ViewData["managerList" + index.ToString()] as SelectList, "- Select -", new { @class = "some-class manager-list", id = "ManagerIDs[" + index + "]" })
       <a class="btn btn-danger delete-manager disabled" href="#" role="button" disabled>Delete</a>
      </div>
     }

     <a id="addManager" class="btn btn-primary add-manager disabled" href="#" role="button" disabled>Add Manager</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Partial View:

```
@{
 // Page setup
 Layout = null;

 // Get the drop down field values from the ViewData object
 ContactsSearchResultsVM managerList = ViewData["managerList"] as ContactsSearchResultsVM;

 // Declarations
 string controlID = "ManagerIDs[" + ViewBag.ManagerID + "]";
}

<div>
 @Html.DropDownList("ManagerIDs", new SelectList(managerList.SearchResults, "ID", "ShortDisplayName"), "- Select -", new { @class = "some-class manager-list", id = controlID })
 <a class="btn btn-danger delete-manager disabled" href="#" role="button" disabled>Delete</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddDepartment(AddDepartmentVM viewModel)
{
    // Declarations
    bool result = false;
    ContactsSearchResultsVM managerList = new ContactsSearchResultsVM(0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    RecordStatusXRefSearchResultsVM recordStatuses = new RecordStatusXRefSearchResultsVM(0, 0, 0, 0, null);


    try
    {
        // Get a list of all possible managers
        managerList = ContactsSearch.SearchContactsTableQuick(new ContactsSearchCriteria
        {
            FromCache = true,
            CacheResults = true,
            CacheDurationInMinutes = 60
        });

        // Get a list of statuses
        recordStatuses = RecordStatusXRefSearch.SearchRecordStatusXRefTable(
                            new RecordStatusXRefSearchCriteria
                            {
                                ExcludeIDs = new List<int>() { 0 }
                            });

        ViewData["managerList"] = managerList;
        ViewData["recordStatuses"] = recordStatuses;


        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.ManagerIDs.Count; i++)
        {
            ViewData["managerList" + i.ToString()] = new SelectList(managerList.SearchResults, "ID", "ShortDisplayName", viewModel.ManagerIDs[i]);
        }

        // Return the view
        return View("AddDepartment", viewModel);
```

Clicking on the Add Manager button will make a call back to the server to the partial view, get the HTML and append that to the form.  Everything is working to submit the data, it's just the pre-selecting of the submitted values in the drop downs that isn't working.

I could do it in jQuery, but I figured I'd try to do it in the initial render if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I had to do was change the front end value to model.ManagerIDs[index] and it worked.